# implicit reads in controller class for PUT function SCALA play framework

Tags: json, scala, slick-3.0, playframework-2.5

Trying to read JSON data from  client and parse it, so I can insert it to the table with a insert method, but my implicit read for Play 2.5 and Slick 3.1.1 , throws an error for Option[BigDecimal], why?

```
object RBooks {implicit val xReads: Reads[xRow] = (
  (JsPath \ "bookId").read[Option[BigDecimal]] and
  (JsPath \ "bookName").read[Option[String]] and
  (JsPath \ "bookDesc").read[Option[String]] and
  (JsPath \ "enabled").read[Option[Char]] and
  (JsPath \ "primaryBook").read[Option[Char]] and
  (JsPath \ "bookType").read[Option[String]] and
  (JsPath \ "bookCurrency").read[Option[String]] and
  (JsPath \ "startDate").read[Option[java.sql.Timestamp]] and
  (JsPath \ "endDate").read[Option[java.sql.Timestamp]] and
  (JsPath \ "allocationsEnabled").read[Option[Char]] and
  (JsPath \ "arrPrefix").read[Option[String]] and
  (JsPath \ "creationDate").read[Option[java.sql.Timestamp]] and    
  (JsPath \ "createdBy").read[Option[String]] and
  (JsPath \ "lastUpdateDate").read[Option[Timestamp]] and
  (JsPath \ "lastUpdatedBy").read[Option[String]]
)(slickLib.xRow.apply  _)
```

Error output I get :

```
No Json deserializer found for type Option[BigDecimal]. Try to implement an implicit Reads or Format for this type.(xRow.apply  _) this code is throwing a error: (JsPath \ "bookId").read[Option[BigDecimal]] and
```

Does `.read` in Play Scala not support Option[BigDecimal]?

Comment: Why do you want `Option[BigDecimal]` instead of `Option[Decimal]`?

Comment: yes, I need to  use Option[BigDecimal], slickLib.xRow.apply _) gets red without it and If I run the code, I get error, I don't understand why scala is not accepting this implicit reads.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `read[Option[Anytype]]`. Use `readNullable[Anytype]` instead.
Example:

```
 (JsPath \ "bookId").readNullable[BigDecimal]
```

For unsupported type you should write own parser or convert from suppoted type to type you want. For example you can deal with `java.sql.Timestamp` like that:

```
import java.sql.Timestamp
(__ \ 'creationDate).readNullable[Long].map(_.map(new Timestamp(_)))
```

Answer (score -1):

Option[BigDecimal] is not supported in play 2.5 scala 12.11.x. The alternative is to use a library like json4s for ORM projects with slick.